# postgres import csv and auto populate ID and created on and updated on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, import, auto-populate

I just switched from sqlite to postgresql for my rails app and attempting to import data into the database via csvs. I have been able to import the data just fine, however, I cannot get the id, created on, and updated on fields to auto populate when I import the csv. I am leaving them blank on the csv file. Is there a way to get those fields to auto populate when I import the csv?

Answer (score 1):

If you want some fields to be set to default values when importing with `COPY`, you need to omit those fields from the `COPY` command.

Instead of:

```
COPY tablename FROM 'somefile.csv' FORMAT csv;
```

you'd write:

```
COPY tablename (col1, col2, col3) FROM 'somefile.csv' FORMAT csv;
```

and *completely omit* the columns from the CSV data, rather than just leaving them blank. 
When you omit the columns, they're automatically set to `DEFAULT`.

Unfortunately PostgreSQL has no option to ignore columns of the input CSV, so the columns of the CSV must match the columns in the `COPY` list. If you can't modify the CSV input, you can `COPY` to a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table with the same structure, then do an `INSERT INTO real_target (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM the_temp_table;`